# Using a function from process.inc.php in a form on another page

Tags: php

I am trying to create a form that has (using the table to do formatting for now.

```
<form action="addcontent()" method="POST" class="formleft">
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" id="id"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Page:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="page"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Information:</td>
            <td><textarea id="info"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add Content">
        </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

how can I use a function called `addcontent()` within `process.inc.php` ?
Any ideas?

Comment: Is `addcontent()` a PHP function or Javascript function? You can't call PHP functions from HTML.

Comment: it was done within PHP sorry for that. I knew can't be done in HTML and my work is being done in PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

- The `action` should be `filename` not function name

  action="process.inc.php"
- and if you want to call this function than you have to use `onSubmit` in form tag for calling this function when submitting the form

  onSubmit="addcontent()"
- For including the content of `process.inc.php` in other file use below code

  include_once("path-to-file/process.inc.php");

Comment: Thanks Yogesh Worked well, My mind was just too overworked with other stuff and just wasn't coming to me.

Comment: `onsubmit="addcontent()"` won't work if it's a PHP function. The content of an `onXXX` attribute must be Javascript.

Comment: ok so if it's for Javascript there Barmar, How would I go about activating the php function on the submit of the process page?